# how to structure role hierarchy in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have this role_hierarchy:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_WEBSITE]
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
```

then

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

non registered users should be able to access to login page,
admin should use the register page (I only want admins to be able to add new users), registered users (both editor or website) should see the homepage (/)

now, if I am a user EDITOR, and I protect a resource with

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_WEBSITE') %}
```

I can see the resource, but this is not what I want. Actually in the profiler I can see:

```
Roles   [ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_USER]
Inherited Roles [ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_WEBSITE]
```

so the editor user is inheriting the ROLE_WEBSITE role. How can I fix that?

thanks
M

full security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_WEBSITE]
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.token_authenticator

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: You'll need to post your full `app/config/security.yml` file for us to see all role information.

Comment: post updated. thanks

Comment: Are you using FOSUserBundle?

Comment: yes Alvin I am using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a few attempts I solved changing the heiriarchy to

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        ROLE_EDITOR
    ROLE_USER:        ROLE_WEBSITE
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
```

Answer (score 0):

1st) Login to MySql (i.e. `mysql -u uname -p` where uname is user try 'root').

2nd) Run this SQL:

```
SELECT id,username,roles FROM fos_user;
```

This will display all the roles given to each user. Then you can see who has "ROLE_EDITOR" and "ROLE_WEBSITE". Then exit mysql.

Use the following (examples) to manage the particular users:

```
php bin/console fos:user:promote uname ROLE_EDITOR
php bin/console fos:user:demote uname ROLE_EDITOR
```

Then, since ROLE_EDITOR & ROLE_WEBSITE sounds like is should be below ROLE_USER, I think you need this change:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: [ROLE_EDITOR,ROLE_WEBSITE] }
```

I think that might work. Try it.
If not, maybe you can filter more based on path prefixes.
Hope this helps.